# Left adjoint functor to zero section embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, derived-functors

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field and let $V$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Set $|V|$ to be total space of the vector bundle, in other words $|V|=\underline{Spec}\operatorname{Sym}(V^\vee)$. Let $s:X \to |V|$ be the zero section embedding. We get a triangulated functor
$$
s^*:D^b(|V|)\to D^b(X).
$$

Does the left adjoint functor $s_!:D^b(X) \to D^b(|V|)$ exist in this situation?

Comment: Sorry but what is $s^*$ ? I am confused because I would say that $s^*$ was a functor $D^b(|V|)\rightarrow D^b(X)$.

Comment: I fixed those typos.